# No alert message when document.ready - jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
});
```

when I refresh the page, there is no alert box. Is there any wrong??

jQuery seems to be added correctly, but I am not able to get the alert for checking whether jQuery is working. Any ideas on how to make the alert show?

Comment: No, that part of your code is fine, must be something else. We cannot help you without more information.

Comment: maybe the page has an javascript error ?

Comment: I went with "not a real question" as opposed to "too localized." There isn't enough information in the question to do more than guess at what the answer should be. You can edit the question to add more information, in which case it *may* be reopened.

Comment: I just came to this question and I find it useful; I'm not sure why it would not be useful!

Answer (score 13):

Did you include the jQuery library before the call in your document?

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("I am an alert box!");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is the right way to include `jQuery` and to confirm whether it is working or not. Thanks @Dennis Traub for the tip.

Answer (score 7):

That should work provided you've loaded jQuery and you haven't used [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). [It works here](http://jsbin.com/exeduy), for instance.

Without more information we can't really help, but here are some tips:

- Look at your browser's JavaScript console for errors. Most likely there's a syntax error elsewhere on the page that's preventing the code you've quoted from ever being run.
- Make sure you've loaded jQuery correctly.
- If you use `noConflict`, change `$` to `jQuery` in your code:

  ```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() { /* ... */ });
  ```

Answer (score 2):

That should definitely work. Be sure to have loaded jQuery before calling that snippets.
Take a look at the javascript console for any error

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities :

1. jquery is not inclided
2. script tag has some typo
3. you might have some other javascript which is creating the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
         alert("I am an alert box!");
    }
})(jQuery);
```

If that doesn't work as well as the other answers then check firebug for errors. You can find it [here](http://getfirebug.com/) if you aren't already using it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include jQuery File in your html page.
put link given below in your html page and you ll have what you want :